# differences between verity and solr

Tags: solr, coldfusion, verity

I'm moving a search from coldfusion 9 verity to coldfusion 10 solr, but i'm getting some weird results.

For example; if i search for "Fishing and Camping England" including the quotation marks on verity i get 7 results, and as you'd expect the results contain the correct phrase "Fishing and Camping England"

But when i search on solr, i get 1 result, and its a result i didn't get back previously. The context shows;

about **fish**! **Camping England** and

If i search the solr collection using different search terms, the results/documents i want are actually there. Is there something strange with solr and search terms in quotation marks? I looked on the Adobe site for solr terms, and it seems it should be fine. Buts it not! I get the same strange results on our local development server and our remote server.

*For this example i changed the actual search words, but I hope you get the idea.*

Comment: Can you ensure "Indexing" is finished?

Comment: Are you using the same field definitions and schema?

Comment: Yes, indexing finished fine. Like i say, if we use other search terms, we can see the files have been indexed.

I'm not sure what you mean by the same field definitions, but both collections are created the same way - cfindex with a type=path extension=.pdf and the key being the path/filename. 

Regarding the schema, we never did anything with any schema on verity, but on solr we had to edit it to make sure the context displayed correctly - as initially it only brought context back if it was contained in the summary, but thats works now.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between working of verity and solr search engine. verity is classic search engine where as Solr is modern.Solr is more robust and fast. [Raymond Camden have explained it well in his blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/10/30/Some-basic-SolrVerity-Differences). 
For difference in result in solr you have to chose a proper serach syntax that will return you desired result. Solr support multiple search syntax to find matching result. Here is some [example of solr search syntax](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS82937B1B-240F-4850-B376-5FD9F911E5E5.html).

Comment: Thanks. I had read both those ( and more! ). On the adobe page the only example of a search string is;

<cfsearch name="qsearch1" 
collection="solr_complex" 
criteria='"Cold Fusiongava" OR "Internet Tools"'> 

from that i'd take it the following should also work;

<cfsearch name="qsearch1" 
collection="solr_complex" 
criteria='"Cold Fusiongava"'> 

or in my case;

<cfsearch name="qsearch1" 
collection="solr_complex" 
criteria='"Fishing and Camping England"'> 

but it doesn't :(

Comment: I would try calling Solr as a web service using CFHTTP and forget about `<cfsearch>`